# Arrays in Eloquent ORM (Laravel 5, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some models:

**Expert**

```
id | name | etc
```

**Place**

```
id | name | etc
```

**Review**

```
id | expert_id | place_id | rates..
```

**Rate**

```
id | name | caption |
```

I need to store rates in Review model (personal, location, internet etc) (or in another model if its not possible). Each Rate haves *name* and *caption*

But how should I add values of more than one rate in review? Maybe arrays or something else?

I have this relations

```
class Place extends Model { 
    public function reviews() { return $this->hasMany('App\Review'); }
}

class Expert extends Model { 
    public function reviews() { return $this->hasMany('App\Review'); }
}
```

I don't know how to make relation Review->Rate, because one review have more than one Rate with value. Where should I store this value? Model Rate contains rate types: only id, name and caption of each rate type.

Comment: How are you dealing with tables sich as expert, places and reviews? Dont you have relationship for any. If you have review table with expert and places id I believe you have done some sort of relationship between models. Isnt? Same rule applies too for creating rates table using one to many relationship with reviews model.

Comment: I have this relations

`class Place extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }
}

class Expert extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }
}`

I don't know how to make relation Review->Rate, because one review have more than one Rate with **value**. Where should I store this value? Model Rate contains **rate types**: only id, name and caption of each rate type.

Comment: Can you show the tables or examples with review and rate? Like an example with data on excel or using a simple text because i havent understood how reviews and rates work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your relationships and relate them together. you can use One-to-One, One-to-Many and Many-to-Many relationships as [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) between Expert, Place, Review and Rate models, to define this relationship, at least four database tables are needed:

experts: `id | name | ...`

places: `id | name | ...`

rates: `id | name | caption | ...`

reviews `id | expert_id | place_id | rate_id | ...`

For example, you can define many-to-many relationship between expert and place like this:

```
class Expert extends Model
{
    /**
     * The places that belong to the user.
     */
    public function places()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place', 'reviews');
    }
}
```

Then you can use `attach`, `detach` and `sync` methods as [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) to insert many-to-many relationships into `reviews` table:

```
$expert = App\Expert::find(1);

$expert->places()->attach($placeId, ['rate_id' => $rateId, '...' => ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be : using one to many relationship. I wouldnt show the code on how to achieve it, until you try something and show some attempt.